# trying to /how to work with dashboard template SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4

Tags: javascript, git, angular, github

download template from
https://github.com/jyinterfly/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4-master

sample demo 
http://rawgit.com/start-angular/SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4/master/dist/dashboard

I found the SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4-master template and downloaded to my local c:\drive. I want to edit the index.html page however the page is blank. and in the online demo dashboard the other webpage htmls don’t exist in the download project.

I like the look and would like to use the dashboard webpage SB-Admin-BS4-Angular-4-master

For example I downloaded the dashboard template sb-admin-bs-4. Located the index.html. The page loads with objects I can edit.
I can locate all the html pages displayed in the demo dashboard.

Have I missed something. What do I need to do to get started.
Im a developer however new to javascript and dashboards

TIA

--dd

Answer (score 0):

The project is developed on angular 4. The pages(components) your looking for can be found on the following path project_folder/src/app and the styles can be found on the following path project_folder/src/styles/. If your not familiar with angular 4, Please go and look at [angular.io](https://angular.io/) site.